# Div appears momentarily on pageload - how do I stop it doing so?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple bit of HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="lk" />
<div id="showDiv">
    <input type="radio" name="lki" id="lki1" value="lki1"> <label for="lki1">Anywhere</label>
    <input type="radio" name="lki" id="lki2" value="lki2"> <label for="lki2">Start</label>
</div>
```

And this JS:

```
// page load
$(document).ready(function () {
  var bla = $('#lk').val();
  if(bla.length > 0){
    $('#showDiv').show();
  }
  else {
    $('#showDiv').hide();
  }
});

// show / hide the "showDiv" content when a user types into the #lk text input field
$('#lk').bind('keyup change',function(){
  if(this.value.length > 0){
    $('#showDiv').show();
  }
  else {
    $('#showDiv').hide();
  }
});
```

There are two parts to the JS. The first should show the `#showDiv' div if the '#lk' text input field contains data.

The second will show / hide `#showDiv' based on whether someone types data into the the '#lk' text input field.

The problem I have is with the first bit of JS, for the page load:

```
// page load
$(document).ready(function () {
  var bla = $('#lk').val();
  if(bla.length > 0){
    $('#showDiv').show();
  }
  else {
    $('#showDiv').hide();
  }
});
```

When the page first loads, the radio buttons in the `#showDiv' div often momentarily appear then disappear if the '#lk' text input field is empty.

When there is content below the form, then the content appears to jump as the  `#showDiv' div appears then is hidden very quickly.

Is there a better way I can use to hide the `#showDiv' div if the '#lk' text input field is empty when the page first loads?

Comment: Can you hide it by default (`display: none`) and only show it when necessary? Now you're hiding it, but only after the entire document is loaded and ready.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add this CSS rule to set an initial status where the DIV isn't shown:

```
#showDiv {
  display: none;
}
```

(That will change depending on the condition in your jQuery function, but this rule will make sure that DIV won't appear for even a milisecond when the page is loaded, before the jQuery function is performed)

Answer (score 3):

The div momentarily shows up because it takes time for the JavaScript to download and execute the logic behind hiding it, so to fix that you need to hide the element by default and then toggle it when it's appropriate.

And as GolezTrol already mentioned in his comment you can do that using `display: none`

Answer (score 1):

Add the below code directly into the element

```
style="display:none"
```

For example

```
<div id="showDiv" style="display:none">
```

This makes the element hidden as soon as the browser renders it. If you hide it via javascript, then the element gets rendered and displayed before the javascript has a chance to hide it.

Hope this helps.